# stripe payment gateway showing error while using test key for integration

Tags: stripe-payments, erpnext, frappe

During testing after filling card and other details , it is throwing an exception showing "Value too big".

Error Log 7: 'Title' (Traceback (most recent call last): File "apps/payments/payments/payment_gateways/doctype/stripe_settings/stripe_settings.py", line 220, in create_charge_on_stripe charge = stripe.Charge.create( File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 122, in request resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 373, in interpret_response self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in handle_error_response raise err stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_lqdXoNF5Y5OCwg: You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments. ) will get truncated, as max characters allowed is 140
Error Log 8: 'Title' (Traceback (most recent call last): File "apps/payments/payments/payment_gateways/doctype/stripe_settings/stripe_settings.py", line 220, in create_charge_on_stripe charge = stripe.Charge.create( File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 122, in request resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 373, in interpret_response self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in handle_error_response raise err stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_lqdXoNF5Y5OCwg: You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "apps/payments/payments/payment_gateways/doctype/stripe_settings/stripe_settings.py", line 202, in create_request return self.create_charge_on_stripe() File "apps/payments/payments/payment_gateways/doctype/stripe_settings/stripe_settings.py", line 236, in create_charge_on_stripe frappe.log_error(frappe.get_traceback()) File "apps/frappe/frappe/**init**.py", line 2261, in log_error return error_log.insert(ignore_permissions=True) File "apps/frappe/frappe/model/document.py", line 263, in insert self._validate() File "apps/frappe/frappe/model/document.py", line 537, in _validate self._validate_length() File "apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 930, in _validate_length self.throw_length_exceeded_error(df, max_length, value) File "apps/frappe/frappe/model/base_document.py", line 964, in throw_length_exceeded_error frappe.throw( File "apps/frappe/frappe/**init**.py", line 534, in throw msgprint( File "apps/frappe/frappe/**init**.py", line 502, in msgprint _raise_exception() File "apps/frappe/frappe/**init**.py", line 451, in _raise_exception raise raise_exception(msg) frappe.exceptions.CharacterLengthExceededError: Error Log 7: 'Title' (Traceback (most recent call last): File "apps/payments/payments/payment_gateways/doctype/stripe_settings/stripe_settings.py", line 220, in create_charge_on_stripe charge = stripe.Charge.create( File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 22, in create response, api_key = requestor.request("post", url, params, headers) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 122, in request resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 373, in interpret_response self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders) File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 152, in handle_error_response raise err stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_lqdXoNF5Y5OCwg: You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments. ) will get truncated, as max characters allowed is 140 ) will get truncated, as max characters allowed is 140

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message is:
"Request req_lqdXoNF5Y5OCwg: You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments." You need to change your integration in order for it to work.